# Eclipse(c++) debugger on mac not displaying variable meaningfully during debug

Tags: c++, eclipse, macos, debugging

I am just starting to learn c++ (I learned a little bit of Java before). I have downloaded the gdb, set up certificates, and set up Eclipse to use the newly installed gdb in order for the debugger to work. However, the debugger seems not displaying meaningful results for variable during debugging.

I am not sure if I should switch to Xcode. Experienced people please let me know your opinion.

My code:

```
    class Animal {
    private:
        string name;
    public:
        Animal() {
            cout << "An animal is being created as new!" << endl;
        }
        ~Animal() {
            cout << "An animal is being deleted!" << endl;
        }
        Animal(const Animal& other) :
                name(other.name) {
            cout << "An animal is being created by copying!" << endl;
        }
        void speak() {
            cout << "My name is " << name << endl;
        }
        void set(string name) {
            this->name = name;
        }
    };

    Animal *create() {
        return new Animal();
    }

    int main() {
        Animal* a1 = new Animal;
        a1->set("cat");
        a1->speak();
        delete a1;
        a1->set("Alice");
        a1->speak();
        Animal* a2 = create();
        a2->set("Bob");
        a2->speak();
        delete a2;
        return 0;
    }
```

And then a screen shot taken when debugging. So the code runs to "a1->speak()". And I just want to take a look at what is in a1, such as a1's member "name". But in the debugging perspective(upper right corner of the screen shot), nothing very meaningful is being displayed.

[image]

Comment: When your tools disappoint you greatly, switch to other tools. Might help.

Comment: What do you mean _"nothing meaningful"_?? It makes perfect sense for me.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ By the time the program runs to "a1->speak()", its member "name" should be set to "cat". But I cannot see it from"Variables" section when I click objects "a1".  Instead it just shows a bunch of numbers I cannot understand(Hex, binary, octal....)